# Why does WatiN timeout when it is indirectly called by a unit test?

Tags: vb.net, watin

I'm using WatiN to run IE inside a VB .NET function:

```
Dim ie8 As New IE("[some website]")
Login(ie8)
Logout(ie8)
```

It runs perfectly fine when I call the function from a console application.

However, when I call the function from a unit test, then WatiN throws a TimeOut exception on the Dim statement.

I tried putting:

```
Dim ie8 As New IE("http://www.google.com")
```

into the unit test and that worked fine.

Does anyone know why things fall apart when I call the function with the Dim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:
Put

```
<STAThread()> _
```

on top of the function that directly calls WatiN.